# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSDictionary' in Swift2.0

Tags: ios, swift

It is probably simple but, since I'm not very experienced at Swift, I can't figure how to port this line to Swift 2.0.

```
func setPasscode(identifier: String, passcode: String) {
    var dataFromString: NSData = passcode.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;

    var keychainQuery = NSDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, identifier, dataFromString], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecValueData])

    SecItemDelete(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef);
    var status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keychainQuery as CFDictionaryRef, nil);
}
```

the error message:
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSDictionary' with an argument list of type '(objects: NSArray, forKeys: [CFString])'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let identifier = "someIdentifier"
let dataFromString = "someData"
let values = [kSecClassGenericPassword, identifier, dataFromString]
let keys: [NSString] = [kSecClass, kSecAttrService, kSecValueData]
let keychainQuery = NSDictionary(objects: values, forKeys: keys)
```